# GitHub Actions "No profiles for 'com.xxx.app' were found" Despite keychain setup

Tags: github-actions, fastlane

I am working on a GitHub Actions CI/CD pipeline setup and, after being tested on my computer, I am unable to make it work on Github actions.

The error I am getting is the following:
[image]

However, before calling gym I call match:
[image]

And before that, on my yaml file I call **create_keychain**:
[image]

Any ideas why the provisioning profile can't be found?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving the issue by using the lane **keychain_create** before calling **match**

```
if is_ci
    create_keychain(
        name: "actions_keychain",
        password: "meow",
        default_keychain: true,
        unlock: true,
        timeout: 3600,
        lock_when_sleeps: false
    )
end
```